# Flash losing variables on hide

Tags: html, css, flash, data-loss

I have a flash file in a div. This div is set to visible (`display:block;`). The div has two sister divs. All three divs are controlled by custom built jQuery tabs, so when another tab is clicked, the currently visible div turns `display:none;`. When the tab is reclicked to set the flashes div to `display:block`, the flash file loses all its values that are stored (for example in a textarea, all the text gets reset, and where a element stores a path to the image, that gets reset).

I have tried other methods like `width:0; height:0;`, which sort of works, but as the flash file is larger than the other two divs, it is still visible underneath. So then I tried `overflow:hidden;` but the same issue still occurs as above (losing values).

`visibility:hidden` isn't applicable as there is a large white space where the flash file should be.

`position:absolute; top:-800px; left:-600px;` loses variables.

`border: 0; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 1px;` also loses variables.

Is there any other method I can use? I have `wmode=transparent` aswell.

Below is the code of my flash embed:

```
<object wmode="transparent" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="690" height="2047" id="gdh_v3_1" align="middle">
            <param  name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="movie" value="gdh_v4.swf?rnd=6389" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
            <param name="FlashVars" value="forcecrop=False&submitted=False&headerfile=&footerfile=&xmlfile=<?php echo $_GET['adfolder'];?>.xml&adfolder=<?php echo $_GET['adfolder'];?>&pics=gld101cc%2Ejpg%2C" />
            <embed wmode="transparent" src="gdh_v4.swf?rnd=6389" FlashVars=forcecrop=False&submitted=False&headerfile=&footerfile=&xmlfile=<?php echo $_GET['adfolder'];?>.xml&adfolder=<?php echo $_GET['adfolder'];?>&pics=gld101cc%2Ejpg%2C" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="690" height="2047" name="gdh_v4" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue years ago, I think you need to use both approchs; **height:0** and **visibility:hidden**. Internet explorer will maintain the flash object even if you hide it to avoid Internet explorer 7 bad render when the height is set to 0 you can add an exception.

Here is a sample code

assume **oldTab** a global var that is set by default to 1, **newT** is set by the click event.

```
if(newT != oldTab){
  if($.browser.msie){
    window.document.getElementById("t"+ oldTab).style.display = "none";
    window.document.getElementById("t"+ newT).style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
    window.document.getElementById("t"+ oldTab).style.height = "0px";
    window.document.getElementById("t"+ oldTab).style.visibility = "hidden";

    window.document.getElementById("t"+ newT).style.height = "auto";
    window.document.getElementById("t"+ newT).style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  oldTab = newT;
}
```

Comment: Ah man, such a simple solution yet perfect! Why didn't I spot that! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is using SharedObjects (AS3) an option for you? Could just store the variables in there.

```
var sh:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("something");

// set values
sh.data.someVar = "Some value";
```

Only issue here is that the values will remain if they view your site any time in the future (which may not be a good thing in your case, then again it might be an awesome one).

Comment: Cheers for the answer mate, unfortunately my knowledge of AS is almost non-existant. If I were to store all my variables in a SharedObject, how would I recall it in the flash? And also, I don't want to play around with this flash file too much, it's not mine and if I break it I'm in the shit. I wonder if there's a more CSS-based answer out there? But if you can enlighten me on the above code that would be great :)

Comment: If you know what the variables that are changing are, you could just prefix them all with **sh.data.** which will make them a property of your SharedObject's data storage. I'll try think of a CSS solution for you. Maybe you could use JavaScript to move the swf off-screen rather than trying to hide it?

Comment: OK, I'll give the SharedObject ago, thank god its EMCA... I've already tried moving off screen with "position" and "margin"

Comment: Found a css answer anyways, see Yacoubs answer